# how to set up arangodb with feather generate custom service (generator-feathers)

Tags: arangodb, yeoman-generator, feathersjs

I've set up a server with feathers-cli

```
feathers geneate app
```

Since there's no default service for Arangodb available I did:

```
feathers generate service
> A custom service
```

I'm searching for examples/docs now, on how to link custom service calls like create, find, get etc. to arangodb or any db for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on how to create your own services can be found [in the services API documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html).

An ArangoDB service that stores data in a collection just looks like this:

```
class Service {
  constructor(collection) {
    this.collection = collection;
  }

  create(data) {
    return this.collection.save(data);
  }
}
```

And you would implement similar functionality for `find`, `update`, `patch` and `remove`.

There are now different ways to initialize the database connection and the service. For some patterns you can refer to how the generator sets up MongoDB or Mongoose, for ArangoDB it probably looks something like this:

```
const { Database } = require('arangojs');

app.set('arangodb', new Database('http://127.0.0.1:8529'));

db.createDatabase('mydb').then(
  () => {
    db.useDatabase('mydb');
    // Initialize the service here
    app.use('/myservice', new Service(db.collection('people')));
  },
  err => console.error('Failed to create database:', err)
);
```

The code of existing adapters, e.g. [feathers-memory](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-memory/blob/master/src/index.js) or one of the [many other database adapters](https://docs.feathersjs.com/ecosystem/readme.html#database) can also be a good reference.

Comment: I still don't understand how/where to do the actual call to the db and return the result into the Promise  
``create (data, params) {
        // ?? db.query(....)
        //            .then(result)``
               
 ``if (Array.isArray(data)) {
          return Promise.all(data.map(current => this.create(current)));
        }

        return Promise.resolve(data);
      }``

Comment: Generate a generic service with the generator and fill in the service class methods with the appropriate database calls.

Comment: I am using generic services and all works well with normal callbacks ``create(data, cb) {.....cb(result)} but I can't get it to work with Promises. I guess I should read more about Promises before continuing. At least I know now for sure that the db calls go inside the .class.js files. thanks.